# Proof for pumping Lemma linear context free language

Tags: pumping-lemma

Where can I find the proof for the linear context free languages pumping lemma?

I am looking for the proof that is specific for the linear context free language

Answer (score 1):

I also looked for the formal prof and could not find one.Not sure if the below is a formal prof but it may give you some idea.

The lemma : For every linear  context free languages L there is an n>0  so that for every w in  L  with |w| > n we can write w as  uvxyz  such that |vy|> 0,|uvyz| <= n  and  uv^ixy^iz  for every i>= 0  is in L.

"Proof":
Imagine a parse tree for some long string w in L with a start symbol S. Also lets assume that the tree does not contains non useful nodes. If  w is long enough, there will be  at least one non terminal repeating more than once. Lets call the first repeating non terminal  going down the tree X, its  first  occurrence (from the top) as X[1] and its second occurrence as X[2].Let x be the string in w generated by X[2], vxy the string generated by X[1]and uvxyz the full string w generated by S. Since the movement from X[1] to X[2] generates v,y we could theoretically generate a new tree where we replicate this move multiple times before moving from X[1] down.This proves that uv^ixy^iz for every i>= 0  is in L. Since our tree contains no useless nodes, moving from X[1] to X[2] must generate some terminals and this proves that |vy|> 0.L is linear which means that on every level of the tree we have a single non terminal symbol. Each node in the tree covers some substring in w that its length is bounded  by a linear function of the node height. Moving from S to X[2] covers uv  and yz from w and the number of tree levels traveled is bounded by (2 * the number of non-terminals symbols + 1). Since the number of levels  traveled is bounded and the tree is linear it also puts a bound on the yield of the movement from S to X[2] which means ,|uvyz| <= n  for some n >= 0.

Note: Keep in mind that we construct X[1] , X[2] top down , in contradiction to how we prove the “regular” pumping lemma for context free grammar in general. In the "regular” pumping lemma there is a bound on the height of X[1] and therefore a bound on |vxy|. In our case there is no bound on the height of X[1]and it can be as high as required by the length of w. There is a bound,however,on the number of tree levels from S to X[2].This does not  means much if the grammar is not linear as the output going from S to X[2] is still bounded only by the high of S (that is unbounded). But in the linear case,this output is bounded and therefore |uvyz| <= n

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!